# PHP - get updated cookie value

Tags: php, cookies

I have a web page based on different PHP source file.

In one of these file, the code updates a cookie value:
setcookie('serial_number', $serial, time()+3600, '/');

In another file I would like to use the updated cookie, 
$serialNew = $_COOKIE['serial_number'];
but I see always the old value, the new is not available until the page refresh.

How can I get the updated value? There is some way to do this? 
Thanks

Comment: You mean to say that both pieces of code run as part of the same request? If so, then you can't access the cookie value via `$_COOKIE` until a new request is made.

Comment: You mean you're doing both `setcookie` and `$_COOKIE` **in the same request**? Then yes, that's how that works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all..

I resolved adding this:
$_COOKIE['serial_number'] = $serial;

so the cookie is updated in every script

Answer (score 0):

Cookies set during a request will be available via `$_COOKIE` on the next page load/next request. They are **not** available in the current request.

You will probably have to store the value in some other variable if you need to access it in the current request.

See also [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on the matter.