# Is it possible to get a cookie's new value after updating it using PHP, without a screen refresh?

Tags: php, cookies

I have used the standard PHP code to update the value of an existing cookie:

```
  $cookie_name = 'user';
  $cookie_value = 'Alex Porter';

  setcookie($cookie_name,
            $cookie_value,
            time() + (86400 * 30),      # 86400 = 24h x 60m x 60s
            '/');
```

However, when I try to display the *new* value in the same script, the *old* value appears.
Here's the PHP:

```
      if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]))
      {
        echo 'Cookie ' . $cookie_name . ' is set!<br>';
        echo 'Value is: ' . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
      } 
      else
      {
        echo 'Cookie named ' . $cookie_name . ' is not set!';
      }
```

According to this [SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973902/php-get-updated-cookie-value), a manual page refresh is necessary before the new value is displayed (Check Robert Rossman's answer):

> Cookies set during a request will be available via $_COOKIE on the next page load/next request. They are not available in the current request.

> You will probably have to store the value in some other variable if you need to access it in the current request.

I'd like to ask:

1. Why is the new value not available in the current request?
2. Is it a caching issue?
3. If it is cache related, is there a way to solve this?
4. Is there any other way to get the new value without a manual page reload?

In fact, if you go to Firefox's Developer Tools - Storage section, the *new* value is correctly displayed though the PHP script displays the *old* value (without a manual page refresh.)

Comment: If I understand setcookie() correctly, it kind of instructs to create cookie header to be sent in response only.. and $_COOKIE contains whatever cookie variables received in request only. 
In your case, I would say you can set same cookie value in $_COOKIE as well along with setcookie and that should solve the problem

Comment: @Riddhish, If I set $_COOKIE, that would be setting it only in the PHP script, right? It's a workaround good enough.

Comment: Yes, setting only in $_COOKIE will be for current script only. To send cookie to browser setcookie() needs to be used.

Comment: According to the above [SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973902/php-get-updated-cookie-value), Robert Rossman also cites the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) on the matter.